# Test if an attribute is present in a tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get all the `<script>` tags in a document and then process each one based on the presence (or absence) of certain attributes.

E.g., for each `<script>` tag, if the attribute `for` is present do something; else if the attribute `bar` is present do something else.

Here is what I am doing currently:

```
outputDoc = BeautifulSoup(''.join(output))
scriptTags = outputDoc.findAll('script', attrs = {'for' : True})
```

But this way I filter all the `<script>` tags with the `for` attribute... but I lost the other ones (those without the `for` attribute).

Comment: "but the if ... in doesn't work"?  What does that mean?  Syntax error?  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Please be very specific on what's going wrong.

Comment: Do you want to test for the presence of an attribute in _any_ tag, _all_ tags or treat each occurrence of the tag separately?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

If i understand well, you just want all the script tags, and then check for some attributes in them?

```
scriptTags = outputDoc.findAll('script')
for script in scriptTags:
    if script.has_attr('some_attribute'):
        do_something()
```

Comment: i'm unable to do something like: if 'some_attribute' in script ? , that's what I'm after, and I want to avoid calling findAll again and again...

Comment: For checking for available attributes you must use python dict methods, eg: script.has_key('some_attribute')

Comment: how do I check if the tag has any attributes? While tag.has_key('some_attribute') works fine, tag.keys() throws an exception ('NoneType' object is not callable).

Comment: found it: tag.attrs is the dictionary!

Comment: Please update this post, has_key is deprecated. Use has_attr instead.

Comment: sadly, did not work for me.
Maybe this way `soup_response.find('err').string is not None` can be used for other attributes too...

Answer (score 49):

You don't need any lambdas to filter by attribute, you can simply use `some_attribute=True` in `find` or `find_all`.

```
script_tags = soup.find_all('script', some_attribute=True)

# or

script_tags = soup.find_all('script', {"some-data-attribute": True})
```

Here are more examples with other approaches as well:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

# Find all with a specific attribute

tags = soup.find_all(src=True)
tags = soup.select("[src]")

# Find all meta with either name or http-equiv attribute.

soup.select("meta[name],meta[http-equiv]")

# find any tags with any name or source attribute.

soup.select("[name], [src]")

# find first/any script with a src attribute.

tag = soup.find('script', src=True)
tag = soup.select_one("script[src]")

# find all tags with a name attribute beginning with foo
# or any src beginning with /path
soup.select("[name^=foo], [src^=/path]")

# find all tags with a name attribute that contains foo
# or any src containing with whatever
soup.select("[name*=foo], [src*=whatever]")

# find all tags with a name attribute that endwith foo
# or any src that ends with  whatever
soup.select("[name$=foo], [src$=whatever]")
```

You can also use regular expressions with find or find_all:

```
import re
# starting with
soup.find_all("script", src=re.compile("^whatever"))
# contains
soup.find_all("script", src=re.compile("whatever"))
# ends with 
soup.find_all("script", src=re.compile("whatever$"))
```

Comment: I agree that this should be the accepted answer. I simplified the primary example to make it stand out more.

Answer (score 38):

For future reference, has_key has been deprecated is beautifulsoup 4.  Now you need to use has_attr

```
scriptTags = outputDoc.find_all('script')
  for script in scriptTags:
    if script.has_attr('some_attribute'):
      do_something()
```

Answer (score 21):

If you only need to get tag(s) with attribute(s), you can use lambda:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(YOUR_CONTENT)
```

- Tags with attribute

```
tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: 'src' in tag.attrs)
```

OR

```
tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.has_attr('src'))
```

- Specific tag with attribute

```
tag = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'script' and 'src' in tag.attrs)
```

- Etc ...

Thought it might be useful.

Comment: Elegant solutions!

Answer (score 3):

you can check if some attribute are present

```
scriptTags = outputDoc.findAll('script', some_attribute=True)
for script in scriptTags:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the pprint module you can examine the contents of an element.

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(vars(element))
```

Using this on a bs4 element will print something similar to this:

```
{'attrs': {u'class': [u'pie-productname', u'size-3', u'name', u'global-name']},
 'can_be_empty_element': False,
 'contents': [u'\n\t\t\t\tNESNA\n\t'],
 'hidden': False,
 'name': u'span',
 'namespace': None,
 'next_element': u'\n\t\t\t\tNESNA\n\t',
 'next_sibling': u'\n',
 'parent': <h1 class="pie-compoundheader" itemprop="name">\n<span class="pie-description">Bedside table</span>\n<span class="pie-productname size-3 name global-name">\n\t\t\t\tNESNA\n\t</span>\n</h1>,
 'parser_class': <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>,
 'prefix': None,
 'previous_element': u'\n',
 'previous_sibling': u'\n'}
```

To access an attribute - lets say the class list - use the following:

```
class_list = element.attrs.get('class', [])
```

You can filter elements using this approach:

```
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    if script.attrs.get('for'):
        # ... Has 'for' attr
    elif "myClass" in script.attrs.get('class', []):
        # ... Has class "myClass"
    else: 
        # ... Do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to select just what you need.

```
outputDoc.select("script[for]")
```