# "has:()" and "not:()" pseudo-classes behaves otherwise when used within BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how `css pseudo-classes` like `not:()` and `has:()` work in the following cases.

The following selector is not supposed to print `27A-TAX DISTRICT 27A` but it does print it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlelement = """
<tbody>
  <tr style="">
     <td><a>27A-TAX DISTRICT</a> 27A</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="">
     <td><strong>Parcel Number</strong> 720</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlelement,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("tr:not(a)").text
print(item)
```

On the other hand, the following selector is supposed to print `I should be printed` but it throws `AttributeError` error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlelement = """
<p class="vital">I should be printed</p>
<p>I should not be printed</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlelement,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("p:has(.vital)").text
print(item)
```

***Where I'm going wrong and how can I make them work?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if an attribute is present in a tag in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015483/test-if-an-attribute-is-present-in-a-tag-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I don't think that it's a duplicate

Comment: If you think this post to be a duplicate one then you should know the reason why my script is behaving otherwise @Zaraki Kenpachi. What is it then?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The user is simply asking about there misunderstanding of how `:has()` and `:not()` operate. Confusion is due to a misunderstanding of how `:has()` and `:not()` actually operate which I have addressed in an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your understanding of what `:not()` and `:has()` does is most likely not correct.

In your first example, you use:

```
soup.select_one("tr:not(a)").text
```

The way you are using it will select every `tr`. This is because it is saying "I want a `tr` tag that is not an `a` tag. `tr` tags are never `a` tags so your code always grabs the text of any `tr` tag, including the one that contains `27A-TAX DISTRICT`.

If you want `tr` tags that don't have `a` tags, then you could use:

```
soup.select_one("tr:not(:has(a))").text
```

What this says is "I want a `tr` tag that does not have a descendant `a` tag".

For more info read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

---

This leads us to your second issue. `:has()` is a relational selector. In your second example, you used:

```
soup.select_one("p:has(.vital)").text
```

`:has()` looks ahead at either children, descendants, or sibling (depending on the syntax you use) to determine if the tag is the the one you want.

So what you were saying was "I want a `p` tag that has a descendant tag with the class `vital`". None of your `p` tags even have descendants, so there is no way one could have a `vital` class. What you want is actually more simple:

```
soup.select_one("p.vital").text
```

What this says is "I want a `p` tag that also has a class `vital`."

For more info read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Yeah, It seems I got them wrong. So `:has()` works when there is any children or sibling. Btw, `:contains()` only looks for text or string but not tag,id, class e.t.c, right? Thanks for the clarity of things @facelessuser.

Comment: `:has()` behavior changes based on the leading combinator: `:has(+ tag)` the very next sibling, `:has(> tag)` is any descendant etc. `:contains()` searches the text under a given tag (included the text in any child tags). It does not look at attributes. For that you'd need to use attribute selectors: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#attribute-selectors.