# Extracting a string from a html tag

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get a string from div data-pair-id which is "14958"

This is my code:

```
urlheader = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

url = "https://www.investing.com/indices/nasdaq-composite"
req = requests.get(url, headers=urlheader)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
x = soup.find('div', id="data-pair-id")
```

But x comes up blank.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please copy paste `urlheader` and also output of `req.content`. So it make easy work for contributors. ;-)

Comment: sorry done, but theres too much stuff in the req.content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.find("div", {'data-pair-id': True}).get('data-pair-id')
    match = re.search(r'smlID = (.*?);', r.text).group(1)
    print(target)
    print(match)


main("https://www.investing.com/indices/nasdaq-composite")
```

Output:

```
14958
2035293
```

Comment: if you have some extra time, could you see if it's also possible to get                                 window.siteData.smlID = 2035293 from the javascript part of the webpage? i need the "2035293"

Answer (score 0):

On the given page, there are only two places `data-pair-id` was found. For both divs, it was not the div's id but an attribute of the div whose value was `14958`.

So, given `data-pair-id`, you can find the attribute's value by finding the first div, passing another parameter specifying the attribute it must have.

```
divs = soup.find('div', {"data-pair-id": True})
print(divs.get('data-pair-id'))
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39055066/11890300

Comment: So does that mean I can’t get the value 14958 any possible way on that page?

Comment: I need to key in something generic to get that value of 14958 because it’ll be different on a different page

Comment: Oh ok. I understood your question wrong. I'll just edit and fix it.

Comment: Umm, typo perhaps? Did you accidentally write ``data-pair-id`` as ``data-pair-is`` in your code?

Comment: my comment was a typo, i meant ```KeyError: 'data-pair-id'```. i checked attributes, i got this ```{'id': 'sideNotificationZone', 'class': ['sideNotificationZone']}```

Comment: Ohk so I understood how to do it. But, someone else has already posted an answer doing the same thing. So, I'll just add a url to my answer.