# Finding strings in tags that do not contain an href attribute directly on in child elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all text from tags h1, h2, h3, span and li that do not containg a href attribute. The objective is to only find strings that are not hyperlinks to some other section of the website or an offsite url.

Here's what I've come up with but unfortunately this also finds those tags that have child elements containing an href attribute

```
soup.find_all(["h1", "h2", "h3", "span", "li"], text=True)
```

example of website

```
<h1 class="footer_nav_title">POLICY</h4>
<ul class="footer_nav_items o-list-bare">
<li class="footer_nav_item"><a href="/pages/return-policy" style="color:">RETURN POLICY</a></li>
<li class="footer_nav_item"><a href="/pages/shipping-information" style="color:">SHIPPING INFORMATION</a></li>
<li class="footer_nav_item"><a href="/pages/terms-of-service" style="color:">TERMS OF SERVICE</a></li>
<li class="footer_nav_item"><a href="/pages/privacy-policy" style="color:">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
```

With my approach the find_all() also finds those tags that have an a element with an href, however Im aming to find only the `<h1 class="footer_nav_title">POLICY</h4>`. How to avoid finding also these href containing tags?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015483/test-if-an-attribute-is-present-in-a-tag-in-beautifulsoup

Comment: Not really. That topic covers finding by attributes within the direct tag. In my case the href attribute is in the child tags or it could be both in h1 and some child tag

Answer (score 1):

Looped through each tag and performed a another search within each separate tag if it contains 'a' tag inside it. If no, then the text inside h1, h2, h2, span, li tags are not hyperlinks but just plain text.

```
for individual_tag in soup.find_all(["h1", "h2", "h3", "span", "li"], text=True):
    if individual_tag.find('a') is None:
        print(individual_tag)
```

Im sure theres a better way of finding non-hyperlink text in the given tags, but looks like this works